# Facebook comment api phonegap

Tags: android, facebook, cordova

did anybody successful include the Facebook comment API (http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/comments/) in his phonegap project on android?

I have successfully implented the facebook plugin for phonegap (https://github.com/davejohnson/phonegap-plugin-facebook-connect) but it doesn't contain any comment functionality.

I want to include facebook comment functionality in my phonegap project on android. Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 4):

my workaround is place the comment plugin on a normal webpage, then use iframe in phonegap to show it.

Answer (score 0):

Facebook plugins are intended for use on a website with a public URL. In a Phonegap app, you're using the HTML5 runtime but the 'pages' are hosted locally as files within the app and there's no URL to key the comments off.

In other words, this isn't possible, and you should be looking at using the comments part of the Graph API programmatically: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/Comment/

Comment: Oke tnx. But when i want to post a comment using: comments/?ids=http://www.yourdomain.com&message=test it do not work. only when i use an id from a facebook post like comments/?ids={ID_NUMBER}&message=test. Do you have a solution?

Comment: Yes, comments are associated with existing Facebook objects. Take this TechCrunch article: http://techcrunch.com/2012/11/07/with-curiosity-peter-molyneux-explores-whether-a-cube-can-capture-the-worlds-attention/ - its comments plugin is showing those associated with object ('webpage') ID 302600566521581, as per http://graph.facebook.com/302600566521581